# warn before leaving the page using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to detect if a user leaves a web page without first saving?

**I have searched before I posted** this question, but I haven't found related topics to deal with `ASP.NET` (I have controls `DropDownList`, `ListBox`, `TextBox`....)

Comment: You cannot detect whether the user turns off the computer

Comment: @john: i am not worried about turns off the computer

Comment: @eglasius: dont think its duplicate i asked specific for asp.net.

Comment: it is a duplicate because the solution is not specific to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the JQuery [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to save off the form's state in the page's `OnLoad` event.  Then serialize the page again in the `OnBeforeUnload` event.  If the values are different, then the page has changed.  You'll have to add a flag to know whether or not the page is unloading because the "Save" button is being clicked.  If the values are different and the user didn't click "Save", then display the "Do you want to save before leaving?" box.

Comment: would you mind showing some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way is to do it the StackOverflow way:

http://www.jonstjohn.com/node/23

Basically it boils down to setting a method to be called in the onbeforeunload javascript event.